# Redirect to wordpress page without page ID

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I'm looking for a way to redirect to a specific wordpress page without knowing the ID.

I have a shortcode that is meant to redirect to a registration page once a button is clicked.

Before, I was able to just use a page ID. Now I am using WPML and the page ID's are all different for each language.

How can I redirect to a specific wordpress page without knowing the specific page ID for the current language?

Comment: create a proxypage, locate the corresponding page id and make another redirect?

Comment: Wouldn't the second redirect have the same problem of not knowing which ID to use based on the language? If not, then could you post an answer with a psuedo example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) or [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).

Both functions accept Post Type as argument, it's not only restricted to "pages". And they will return a full `$post` object, ie, `$post->ID`.

Maybe a WPML function is needed, an equivalent of those. Or maybe a combination.
See the docs for [Language dependent IDs](http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/language-dependent-ids/).

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at those. I think the issue is the same. With WPML, the page ID and title can both be different for each language.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.wpmayor.com/step-by-step/build-multilingual-site-wpml/ see the third subhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom field which will be shared by all versions of the same article, and then query by that instead. Something like an article GUID.

Comment: WOW That's a pretty far-out idea. Unfortunately, it is not even approachable here. Interesting how Wordpress has never made it easier to access pages.